# Is there a text file containing my MongoDB data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been using MongoDB atlas for a while now, and have decided to start hosting the database locally.  After creating a new collection, completing all the standard steps, with no errors, and adding a new object with mongoose, I don't see the collection in my data/db file.  Is there a different place where I should be looking to find plain text, as such in Atlas?

Comment: What is your OS? What do you see in data/db? Can you see your data in the mongo shell? On Ubuntu you don't see your actual collection name but you do see collections looking something like `collection-4-11911244524553325.wt` and the modified date is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many databases, MongoDB does not store data in plain text files. It does use files but these files are binary and generally not usable directly by users.

Atlas does not provide filesystem access in any event, so whatever files it does use you won't be able to retrieve.

To extract your data, use a tool like mongodump.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/import-export/#id1) from the MongoDB docs.

It shows how to export the data as json or csv from Atlas

Comment: I want to transition out of atlas, but I can't find the data I put in my collection.(not in Atlas)

Comment: @ModestPelicanProgramming is the data in a local MongoDB instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the mongodump of your data from the atlas cluster and later on you can mongorestore it to your local deployment.
mongodump : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump

mongorestore : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore